# question about median of two array

Tags: algorithm

here is   pseudo code   on  algorithm to find median of two array

```
T WO -A RRAY-M EDIAN (X, Y )
n ← length[X]                  £ n also equals length[Y ]
median ← F IND -M EDIAN (X, Y, n, 1, n)
if median = NOT- FOUND
   then median ← F IND -M EDIAN (Y, X, n, 1, n)
return median
F IND -M EDIAN ( A, B, n, low, high)
if low > high
   then return NOT- FOUND
   else k ← (low + high)/2
        if k = n and A[n] ≤ B[1]
           then return A[n]
        elseif k < n and B[n − k] ≤ A[k] ≤ B[n − k + 1]
           then return A[k]
        elseif A[k] > B[n − k + 1]
           then return F IND -M EDIAN ( A, B, n, low, k − 1)
        else return F IND -M EDIAN ( A, B, n, k + 1, high)
```

it is from   introduction of algorithms MIT

and  here is my code please if something is wrong in my code  tell  me

```
    public class findmedian{
public static  int   find(int []x,int []y){
int median;
int n=x.length;
   median=Median( x, y, n,0, n);
  if ( median<-100000){
    Median(y,x, n,1, n);

}

 return median;  


 }


public static void main(String[]args){
 int x[]=new int[]{3,5,7,8,5,9,10};
 int y[]=new int[]{12,4,8,9,6,7,10};
find(x,y);


}

public static  int  Median(int []a,int []b,int n,int low,int high)
{


   if ( low>high)
 return -1  ;
  int k=(low+high)/2;
  if (k==n  && a[n]<=b[1])
   return a[n];
 else   if ( k<n && b[n-k]<=a[k] && b[n-k]<=b[n-k+1])
 return a[k];
   else if ( a[k]> b[n-k-1])
 return   Median( a,b,n,low,k-1);





 return  Median(a,b,n,k+1,high);





}


}
```

after compile it does not return anything please help

Comment: If you format your code properly it will make it easier to read and debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ( low>high)
 return;
```

Is this the error? You need to return *something*. (The return type is int)